# Replace iOS 11 Smart Punctuation With JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, smart-punctuation

[So I found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678359/ios-11-safari-html-disable-smart-punctuation), which provides some great insight into the problem of smart punctuation from iOS, but I want to do the replacements wholesale, i.e. on a complete string, not as input is being entered by the user.

I looked around and it seems as though unicode characters are supported in ES6 through using `\u<<code point>>`. Does this work on matching with regex?

I've got this string:

```
"This is a message from iOS with it’s so-called “smart” punctuation.
```

I have been trying a test replacement with this:

```
x.replace(/\u8220/g, 'XXXX');
```

and I can verify that code point is in the string (via dev tools JS console):

> ```
> > x.charCodeAt(47);
> 8220
> ```

But the output from my call to replace is the same string, unchanged. I've also tried wrapping the unicode part in `[]` but with no luck. Am I being dumb or is this just not supported in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8220 is the *decimal* value for the left double quote. To use `\uXXXX` you need to specify the *hex* value of the codepoint, in this case `\u201C`.

Here's an expression that would replace all of the “curly” quotes in a string with "straight" quotes:

```
s.replace(/[\u2018\u2019\u201C\u201D]/g, (c) => '\'\'""'.substr('\u2018\u2019\u201C\u201D'.indexOf(c), 1));
```

Comment: Son of a.... I knew it'd be something stupid! I noticed other questions were using hex values and incorrectly assumed 8020 was hex.